# Design pattern to recreate an Object when the same Object runs a callback

Tags: java, websocket, callback

This is a dumbed-down toy example of what I'm trying to do.

I have a WebSocket class which implements a method `onClose()`. When the Socket closes, it fires an event handler (lambda function).

```
public class WebSocket {
  ICallback cb;

  public WebSocket(ICallback cb) {
      this.cb = cb;
      this.onClose(); // Simulating socket closing
  }

  public void onClose() {
    this.cb.handle();
  }

  @FunctionalInterface
  public static interface ICallback {
    public abstract void handle();
  }
}
```

In a parent class, I create a new instance of this class. When the socket closes, I have to recreate a new instance of this class. (Old one is unusable)

This is my implementation

```
class Parent {
  static WebSocket socket;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Parent.createSocket();
  }

  public static void createSocket() {
    Parent.socket = new WebSocket(() -> { Parent.createSocket(); });
  }
}
```

This code works

but whenever the `onClose()` is fired, a new frame is added onto the stack. If left to run long enough and assuming a number of errors causing the sockets to close, it'll eventually cause a `StackOverflowError`.

**[Running Example](https://repl.it/repls/GigaBouncyNumerators)**

What's the best pattern to recreate the `WebSocket` object without increasing the stack size?

Is running a thread which continuously checks the state of the socket a viable approach?
i.e:

```
while(socket.isOpen()) {
 Thread.sleep(1000);
}
createSocket();
```

Comment: But surely your web socket doesn't immediately close in the constructor, does it? It's surely going to close asynchronously with your other code, right?

Comment: @Sweeper It doesn't. This is just a toy example to help me demonstrate the issue I'm trying to explain

Comment: Then you don't have a problem. The stack size won't increase infinitely.

Comment: I think we need to see a slightly less "toy" example... something reflecting how this would actually work in the real world.  Otherwise I fear this might be an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)

Comment: @Sweeper Going with this approach is just kicking the can down the road. Eventually, it'll be a problem when the stack is full. This is a server running code and therefore I don't think it's ideal for it to be susceptible to this. Eitherway, this issue can be abstracted out to a number of different examples and therefore I'm simply looking for an alternative design pattern

Comment: Also, don't you really just want a WebSocket connection pool that manages the connections for you?

Comment: @JimGarrison what/how would the connection pool do this differently? Perhaps that's a design pattern I could use

Comment: How is `onClose() ` triggered in your real world example?

Comment: @daniu. onClose can be triggered for a number of reasons. Network error, authentication token expiry, inactivity just to name a few. I'm really just trying to implement a reconnection logic.

Comment: But doesn't the socket live in a separate thread that finishes when closing, so you can just start it new?

Comment: @daniu well to start a new one, I need a way to know when the old one dies. So I went with the callback approach which notofies me when a socket closes so I can start a new one. But as explained in my post, I face the stack issue

Comment: 'Old one is unusable' why?

Comment: @user207421 because once it closes do to reasons explained in a few comments above, it can't be reopened. A new socket object needs to be created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for your stack overflow is that your callback never finishes - you just create a new socket and run it, but the old one stays active. Same for the next one, and so on.

So one way of handling this is to do the socket creation concurrently to give the `onClose()` method a way to actually terminate.

You can do that by submitting the actual creation to an `ExecutorService`; a single-threaded one is fine because after all, you only want one socket running at a given time.

```
class Parent {
    static WebSocket socket;
    // this is where the socket runs
    private static final ExecutorService EXECUTOR = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        createSocket();
    }

    private static void createSocket() {
        Parent.socket = new WebSocket(() -> {
            EXECUTOR.submit(Parent::createSocket);
        });
    }
}
```

This way, when the callback is called by `onClose()`, it returns immediately, having submitted the creation of a new web socket. That creation hasn't happened yet because the executor is single threaded, and the previous socket still runs in that thread. But once it finishes, the next submission is executed - namely the creation that was just submitted.

As a side note, it's pretty much always a good idea to have network connections running concurrently, so the main thread is still available for other tasks.

Comment: Perfect! This was what I was looking for. Thank you!